# How to find the frequency of digits in a number using a switch statement?

Tags: c++, numbers, switch-statement, frequency, digits

For my college intro to computer science class we must write a program which outputs frequency of digits in a given integer. For example, if the number is 124243294 the output is:

```
Number Frequency
1      1
2      3
3      1
4      2
9      1
```

You **must** use the switch statement to obtain the frequency of the digits.

Comment: What is your question? Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You are encouraged to [edit] your post at anytime to clarify what exactly is preventing you from solving this yourself

Comment: If you can avoid it, don't use a numeric type. Try to take the number as a `std::string` because it is much, MUCH easier to separate the digits. You can easily convert a character into the corresponding number (assuming that the character is a legitimate digit - test to prove it is before using it) by subtracting the `'0'` from the character.

Comment: @user4581301 Okay thank you very much I will remember that in the future !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```cpp
int number;
std::cin >> number;

std::string s = std::to_string(number);
int freq[10] = {};

for(char ch : s)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            freq[ch - '0']++;
            break;
    }
}

std::cout << "Number Frequency\n";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (freq[i] != 0)
        std::cout << std::setw(7) << std::left << i << freq[i] << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/0Avj0X)

But, why must a `switch` be used? I would use a `std::(unordered_)map` instead, eg:

```cpp
int number;
std::cin >> number;

std::string s = std::to_string(number);
std::map<char, int> freq;

for(char ch : s) {
    freq[ch]++;
}

std::cout << "Number Frequency\n";
for(auto &elem : freq) {
    std::cout << std::setw(7) << std::left << elem.first << elem.second << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/RcmXI3)

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much. The only reason I was forced to use a switch statement is because the professor requested it. Thanks!

Comment: I very much doubt that this is the use-case the professor had in mind, but you didn't provide any other requirements/instructions for us to work with, and this works.